# how to check if only the selected element has a duplicate in array

Tags: python

```
from collections import Counter

selected_element = 3
arr = [1,2,3,4,3,5,5]


def duplicates(values):
    dups = Counter(values) - Counter(set(values))
    return list(dups.keys())
print(duplicates(arr))
```

output:
**[3, 5]**

I want only the selected element to be displayed which is **3** how would I do that?

Comment: ill just print the `selected_element` together with its index position

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily use count :

```
selected_element = 3
arr = [1,2,3,4,3,5,5]
print(arr.count(selected_element)>1)
```

count of selected element should be greater than 1 if it has any duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether `selected_element` is in `dups`.

```
print(selected_element in duplicates(arr))
```